# Performing actions across a list

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames, all containing numeric data. How would I go about changing the internal data.frames such that NA values = 0 and anything > or = 1, equals 1. Basically, convert to a data.frames of zero and one.

A quick example.

```
x <- list()
x$a <- data.frame(c(NA, NA, 7, 7, NA), c(1,1,NA,NA,NA))
x$b <- data.frame(c(NA, NA, 7, 7, NA), c(1,1,NA,NA,NA))
x$c <- data.frame(c(NA, NA, 7, 7, NA), c(1,1,NA,NA,NA))
```

Generally, if I was only doing one I would do something like:

```
x$a[x$a >= 1] <- 1
x[is.na(x$a)] <- 0
```

Now, how do I apply that across an entire list?

UPDATE: Anyone care to add a solution with ldply() for good measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a shorter / more efficient solution, but this works:

```
lapply(x, function(y) {y[y >= 1] <- 1; y[is.na(y)] <- 0; y})
```

Comment: On a list of 5 data.frames worth 10.000 rows each, this solution comes first (10 replicates takes 0.13 s) (then Chase's (0.31 s) and then Ramnath's (2.3 s)).

Answer (score 3):

Nest apply within lapply:

```
lapply(x, function(x) 
    apply(x, 2, function(y) ifelse(is.na(y), 0, ifelse(y >= 1, 1, y))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another really convoluted way to do it. It works by first replacing all NAs by a 0, and then picking the minimum of a number and 1. This is just for the sake of illustration and fun, and is NOT recommended since it is nightmarish code to maintain!

```
lapply(lapply(x, function(y) replace(y, is.na(y), 0)), sapply, pmin, 1)
```

Comment: I thought of a similar solution, but it will not provide correct answers if there are negative numbers and the OP wanted to keep them as they were.

Comment: @Joshua. You are right. I edited the solution to account for this behavior